# Is it possible to do partitioning using GParted while OS is running ?

Tags: partitioning

It ok to make new partitions when system is already installed? Just open GParted and start to make new partitions, Or is it recommended during OS installation process?

Comment: you want to make partitions from the drive in which you already have OS ?

Comment: I have EXT4 ./ partition and two NTFS and I wish to resize one of this NTFS partitions for /home partition and /media that's the question is it ok to break/resize NTFS mounted partion?

Comment: Well, in my case I don't use any partition manager and being on GPT layout. The solution which can be wrapped into some semi-auto script is to create temporary root in memory, switching to it, do changes to your original root and then switch again back. http://www.ivarch.com/blogs/oss/2007/01/resize-a-live-root-fs-a-howto.shtml

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot `move/resize/delete` a mounted partition in Gparted.If you boot ubuntu,at the time of booting your ubuntu partition will automatically mounted.so after booting into ubuntu,gparted can't able to `resize/delete` your ubuntu partition.

If you want to make partitioning on Ubuntu partition,the only option is `Gparted-live-disk`.Because gparted on a live disk booted up(live disk partition only mounted,it was like /`dev/sdb` or `/dev/sdc`)but the hard-disk partitions was not mounted(it was like `/dev/sda`).

Answer (score 1):

GParted won't adjust any partition that's currently in use, but it should be able to alter partitions that are *not* currently mounted and create new partitions in unpartitioned areas of the disk. In some cases you can unmount a mounted partition (GParted can do this, in fact), but you will never be able to unmount your root (`/`) partition, and possibly not some others. If you need to adjust them, you'll need to boot from a live CD to edit the partitions.

Some other tools, such as the text-mode `fdisk` and `gdisk`, do enable you to edit partitions that are in use; however, these tools don't support filesystem resizing, and if you edit in-use partitions the kernel won't use the changes until after you reboot.

If this information isn't sufficient, you'll need to post more details about what you want to know -- what type of editing do you need to do, what are your current partitions, etc.

Comment: I'm actually planning to resize/break mounted NTFS partition in two parts one /home and one for /media this partition was installed back then when Windows Xp was installed so now I want to make /home out of it and /media also.

Comment: See [this site](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Partitioning/Home/Moving) for information on what you're planning to do. You should be able to do it from your standard system, provided you unmount the NTFS volume first; but if GParted refuses to do something because the disk is in use, using a live CD should help.

Comment: thank you that helped just one more question to this article if I understand it right: <<Manual Partitioning" during the installation of Ubuntu and specifying that you want your home partitions mount point to be /home, ensure you mark your /home partition not be formatted in the process.>> So after I resized/break my NTFS partition into two parts and that part that I choose to be default ./home partition should be left unformatted? because I have EXT4 ./ partition and it'll be connected with ./home right?

Comment: When you first create it, you'll need to create a filesystem on ("format") `/home`. Thereafter, you should not do so unless you want to delete all files on the partition. That's the key point, really -- "formatting" a partition *erases all the files on it.* If you want to do that, then go ahead and create a new filesystem; if not, avoid doing so.